# Size of images for UI for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, image, user-interface, uibutton, autolayout

If I want to set a button's background image in iOS in an app that uses autolayout, what size should the .png image be? Since the height, and width of the button will always vary, in addition to accommodating for retina/nonretina displays (@2x?).

Comment: Look up how to use resizable images.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple images with providing proper naming conventions normal, @2x, @3x, ~iPad etc.

For that go through Apple documentations.
For example, your image name is `myBackground.png` then

```
[UIImage imageForDeviceWithName:@"myBackground"];
```

Then here is the list of files and resolutions for "`myBackground`"

> myBackground@2x.png == 960 × 640
>
> myBackground-568h@2x.png == 1136 × 640
>
> myBackground-667h@2x.png == 1334 × 750
>
> myBackground@3x.png == 2208 × 1242
>
> myBackground~ipad.png == 1024 × 768
>
> myBackground@2x~ipad.png == 2048 × 1536

Same way you require to add images for landscape with suffix added like: `~Landscape`

Comment: Bit big for a button background.

Comment: That's just an example give with full screen size, (Splash screen). One has to maintain the ratio as per this example.

Answer (score 0):

When You are using **Image** for particular **Button** then you should note down the following point

- When your **Button** is size of **50x100** then the **Image** should be with size **50x100** for **non-ratina**. and  **Button** is size of **50x100** then the **Image** should be with size **100x200** for **Ratina**.

In short doesn't matter with your **Button** size. when you are using any **Image** with **X** size for **Non Ratina** then for **Ratina** display required same **Image** with **2X** (double size) image.

**X** size for **Non Ratina**

**2*x**  size for **Ratina**

because it will work every device but your **Button Image** will not seen properly.